# How to keep empty line in Dart code inside curly braсets?

Tags: android-studio, dart

How to keep empty line in dart code inside curly braсets? By default, Android studio automaticaly removes them. How to change that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Don't fight the formatter. It will win.

The way to avoid a `{` and `}` being collapsed is to have something between them.
I'd recommend something like:

```dart
Future<void> displayRangePicker(BuildContext context) async {
  // Intentionally left empty.
}
```

or even just:

```dart
Future<void> displayRangePicker(BuildContext context) async {
  return;
}
```

(which is equivalent to what you wrote, just being explicit about the return).